# Grid 960 bug in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, 960.gs

If you go to the "Variable Grid System" generator
and have:

column width = 20

number of columns = 12

and gutter width = 60

...the system provides a content width 
of 900 and a full width of 960.

http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/

Now, this is all fine and dandy in Firefox, Chrome, 
and even IE6, but when you load those settings in IE8, 
you end up with the *actual* full width as **1000px**, 
not 960px.

Has this issue been encountered before?

Comment: This question should be CLOSED.

Comment: But maybe this will be useful for future reference... My problem was the result of having IE's ZOOM level at 125%. At what point I had changed that, I don't know. But re-setting the zoom level to 100% eliminated the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments: my problem was the result of having IE's ZOOM level at 125%. At what point I had changed that, I don't know. But re-setting the zoom level to 100% eliminated the issue.